# Regex for string matching with special escaping rule

Tags: python, regex, string, escaping

I'm trying to match special kind of string literals with some funky escaping rules.

The general form looks like this:

```
"some string"
```

Which are simple to match using a pattern such as "(.*?)"

However you can escape quotes by doubling them, such as:

`"hello "" there"` becomes `hello " there`
`"hello """" there"` becomes `hello "" there`

And this is where my regex skills fail me. How can I match strings like this?

Oh, and I'm using python 3.1.

Comment: I think that this way of formatting is better. Feel free to rollback if you don't think so.

Comment: It definitely looks better.

Comment: Although, I'm still not sure what you are trying to do. You have input strings as `"hello "" there"` and `"hello """" there"` and want the output to be `hello " there` and `hello "" there` respectively or?

Comment: The regex doesn't have to unescape the string, I can do that later, however I need to match the entire string. My current pattern stops matching when hitting the double " while it should continue until the first " which isn't doubled.

Comment: what would you expect in case of `"""`? Can you match the string first and then replace the quotes?

Comment: The first two " would be unescaped into a single " and the third " would terminate the string. And yes I can replace the quotes later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
regex = re.compile(r'"(?:[^"]|"")*"')
```

This just finds the literals, it doesn't decode them by replacing the doubled quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Not using a regular expression, but you've specified Python, so here's a way to get your expected output:

```
>>> import csv
>>> strings = ['"some string"', '"hello "" there"', '"hello """" there"']
>>> for s in strings:
    print next(csv.reader([s]))


['some string']
['hello " there']
['hello "" there']
```